# How can I add the values for same groups until the second last index level of a nested Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a minimal example of a nested pandas dataframe from a nested dictionary based on the instructions given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175233/can-i-create-a-nested-column-pandas-dataframe-using-a-nested-dictionary/78175296#78175296).

```
nested_dict = { 'Full_Grades': {
    'Science_Marks': {
        'Physics': {
            'Theo': 99,
            'Prac': 100
        },
        'Biology': {
            'Theo': 89,
            'Prac': 100
        }
    },
    'Finance_Marks': {
        'Economics': {
            'Theo': 99,
            'Prac': 100
        },
        'Accounting': {
            'Theo': 89,
            'Prac': 100
        }
    }
    }
}
```

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.concat({k: pd.concat({k2: pd.DataFrame(v2) for k2,v2 in v.items()}, axis = 1)
                  for k, v in nested_dict.items()}, axis = 1) .unstack().to_frame().T
print(out)
```

Here is the output -

```
    Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades
    Science_Marks   Science_Marks   Science_Marks   Science_Marks   Finance_Marks   Finance_Marks   Finance_Marks   Finance_Marks
    Physics Physics Biology Biology Economics   Economics   Accounting  Accounting
    Theo    Prac    Theo    Prac    Theo    Prac    Theo    Prac
0   99      100     89      100     99      100     89      100
```

Can anyone suggest a technique to add the numbers with same groups until the second last index level. For instance the total of `Physics` (under the group `Full_Grades-Science_Marks-Physics`) will be 199. It's okay if the last index level names are different (`Theo` and `Practical`).

For this post I don't have any work to show, as I really don't know how to even begin. Also, apologies if the question title or contents aren't clear. I wrote them to the best of my ability. Let me know if any further clarification is required.

Edit 1: Here is the output I am looking for -

```
    Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades Full_Grades
    Science_Marks   Science_Marks   Science_Marks   Science_Marks   Finance_Marks   Finance_Marks   Finance_Marks   Finance_Marks
    Physics Physics Biology Biology Economics   Economics   Accounting  Accounting
    Theo    Prac    Theo    Prac    Theo    Prac    Theo    Prac
0   99      100     89      100     99      100     89      100
Sum     199            189             199             189
```

Also, I'd appreciate a way to access the values corresponding to row `0` so that I can do various analysis such as sum, average, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `unstack`, use `sum` to aggregate the rows:

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.concat({k: pd.concat({k2: pd.DataFrame(v2) for k2,v2 in v.items()}, axis = 1)
                  for k, v in nested_dict.items()}, axis = 1).sum().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
    Full_Grades                                 
  Science_Marks         Finance_Marks           
        Physics Biology     Economics Accounting
0           199     189           199        189
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'd like to have the previous row and *then* do analysis on it.

Comment: I just realized that my question is a duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272452/sum-columns-by-level-in-a-pandas-multiindex-dataframe

I think I'll just delete it. What do you think?

Comment: It's up to you. Summing is an existing question, what was important here, however, was to realize that you can use such summing step in your reshaping. No worries if you prefer to delete.