# How to `pd.concat` nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying concatenate multiple DataFrames using `pd.concat`. Basically I am trying to follow the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175233/can-i-create-a-nested-column-pandas-dataframe-using-a-nested-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment137819708_78175233) post for a four level nested dictionary.

Here is my attempt with a minimal example -

```
import pandas as pd
nested_dict = {
    'level1': {
        'level2': {
            'level3': {
                'level4': 'value'
            }
        }
    }
}

for key0, value0 in nested_dict.items():
    for key1, value1 in value0.items():
        for key2, value2 in value1.items():
            for key3, value3 in value2.items():
                out = pd.concat(key3:{pd.DataFrame(key2:{pd.DataFrame(key1:{pd.DataFrame({key0: pd.DataFrame(value0)})})})}, axis = 1)
```

Unfortunately, I get the error -

```
    out = pd.concat(key3:{pd.DataFrame(key2:{pd.DataFrame(key1:{pd.DataFrame({key0: pd.DataFrame(value0)})})})}, axis = 1)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the output that I am looking for -

```
  level1
  level2
  level3
  level4
0  value
```

Edit -

I followed the instructions given in the answer -

```
for key0, value0 in nested_dict.items():
    for key1, value1 in value0.items():
        for key2, value2 in value1.items():
            for key3, value3 in value2.items():
                out = pd.concat({key3:pd.DataFrame({key2:pd.DataFrame({key1:pd.DataFrame({key0: pd.DataFrame(value0)})})})}, axis = 1)
```

Now, I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thoma/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.2/scratches/scratch_14.py", line 16, in <module>
    out = pd.concat({key3:pd.DataFrame({key2:pd.DataFrame({key1:pd.DataFrame({key0: pd.DataFrame(value0)})})})}, axis = 1)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 663, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 494, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 119, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 657, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Edit 2: I tried `out = pd.concat([{key3:pd.DataFrame([{key2:pd.DataFrame([{key1:pd.DataFrame([{key0: pd.DataFrame(value0)}])}])}])}], axis = 1)`

But now I get the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thoma/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.2/scratches/scratch_14.py", line 16, in <module>
    out = pd.concat([{key3:pd.DataFrame([{key2:pd.DataFrame([{key1:pd.DataFrame([{key0: pd.DataFrame(value0)}])}])}])}], axis = 1)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 369, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 459, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: The error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" indicates that there is a syntax error in the code, such as a typo or incorrect grammar. It is not recommended to ask questions on Stack Overflow about errors caused by typos or grammar without first checking the code yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I apologize for this mistake.

Comment: You should use the `json_normalize` approach in the answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78175233/9473764), then you wouldn't have these issues

Comment: My `json_normalize` approach would work for any depth. Just ensure that you don't have periods in the keys. If you do, use a different separator during normalization/split.

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are just slightly wrong.
Instead of having `Key:{Value}` you need `{Key:Value}`.

So in your example, the brackets need to be corrected to

```
pd.concat({key3: pd.DataFrame(...
```

But for all `key:value` pairs you need to correct this.

EDIT:

For the new error, you can simply just place each new `pd.DataFrame` into a list

```py
pd.concat([{key3: pd.DataFrame([...])}])
```

Notice that the `key3` is now in a list, as well as `key2` dataframe. Repeat for the others.

Comment: I fixed that bug, but another bug came up.

Comment: See my edit for an answer